# Why am I getting a syntax error while naming an empty list in python sublime text 3?

Tags: python, sublimetext3

The empty `odds` list is being highlighted orange similar to a number in sublime. I am getting an invalid syntax, tried renaming it all kinds of things still get the same error.

```
max_num = int(input(['enter number'])
    
odds = []
    
    for x in range(max_num):
        if x % 2 != 0
            odds.append(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an end parens on the first line.

```py
max_num = int(input(['enter number']) ) # <--- you need a second parens, one for input and then one for int
```

Answer (score 0):

open parentheses on the first line caused it to mistake the list as a keyword parameter.